# twitter bootstrap: show progress bar with percent centered

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar

I'd like to use these progress-bars: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#progress-low-percentages

but show the percent in the middle of the bar no matter the current value, and not centered in the colored part of the bar

any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

*Here is a way :*

**Bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/TXVFiHpR7j

**HTML**

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 60%;">
    <span class="my-centered">60% Complete</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.my-centered{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

With a bit of css:

```
.progress-bar {
  float: inherit;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```